# How can I get R to recognize my variable as POSIXct so that it breaks up my x-axis into intervals?

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, posixct

I'm trying to get the average temperature over 60 min based on the groupings in the code below group_by(Type, Rainfall, datetime). I've done this, however, when I try to graph it, my graphs are clearly not recognizing my new "interval" variable as being in POSIXct format, even though I've tried to reformat it and checked its class to make sure (this came back with: "POSIXct" "POSIXt"). I'm not sure if the issue here is that it's somehow both in POSIXct and POSIXt or if it's something else, but any help on the matter would be great! My ultimate goal here is to not having a million datetime labels on my x-axis. I've tried using scale_x_datetime to add breaks on my x-axis, but again, since it won't recognize my intervals as datetime, it gives me an error saying that it's not in POSIXct.

```
df_Temps1 <- df_Temps1 %>% 
  mutate(interval = cut(datetime, breaks = "60 min"))

# calculate mean values for line graphs 
df_Temps1.means <- df_Temps1 %>% 
  group_by(Type, Rainfall, interval) %>% 
  summarise(Temp_mean=mean(temperature, na.rm=TRUE), n=n(), sd=sd(temperature, na.rm=TRUE), se=sd/sqrt(n))
df_Temps1.means$se<-as.numeric(df_Temps1.means$se)
df_Temps1.means$Temp_mean<-as.numeric(df_Temps1.means$Temp_mean)
df_Temps1.means

df_Temps1$interval <- as.POSIXct(df_Temps1$interval, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
class(df_Temps1$interval)
```

[image]

```
p1 <- ggplot(df_Temps1.means, aes(x=interval, y=Temp_mean, color=Type)) + 
  aes(group=Type) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Temp_mean-se, ymax=Temp_mean+se), width=0.1) +
  geom_line(aes(color=Type, linetype=Type), linewidth=1) +
  geom_point(size=0.5) +
  xlab("Time") + 
  ylab("Temperature (ºC)") +
  scale_color_manual(values = my_colors) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1), axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-1), legend.position="top",
        legend.text = element_text(size=12), legend.title = element_blank(), legend.key.size = unit(1, 'cm'),
        legend.background = element_rect(size = 0.5, linetype = "solid", colour = "black")) +
  facet_grid(~Rainfall) 
p1
```

Here's a snippet of my data to play with:

```
structure(list(Type = c("", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", 
"Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", 
"Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", 
"Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", 
"Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", 
"Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", 
"Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", 
"Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", "Brown SAPE", 
"Brown SAPE", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", 
"Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", 
"Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", 
"Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", 
"Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", 
"Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", 
"Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", 
"Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", "Brown STSA", 
"Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", 
"Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", 
"Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", 
"Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", 
"Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", 
"Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", 
"Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", 
"Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green SAPE", "Green STSA", 
"Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", 
"Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", 
"Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", 
"Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", 
"Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", 
"Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", 
"Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA", 
"Green STSA", "Green STSA", "Green STSA"), Rainfall = c(NA, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), interval = structure(c(NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L), levels = c("2022-07-24 11:00:00", 
"2022-07-24 12:00:00", "2022-07-24 13:00:00", "2022-07-24 14:00:00", 
"2022-07-24 15:00:00", "2022-07-24 16:00:00", "2022-07-24 17:00:00", 
"2022-07-24 18:00:00", "2022-07-24 19:00:00", "2022-07-24 20:00:00", 
"2022-07-24 21:00:00", "2022-07-24 22:00:00", "2022-07-24 23:00:00", 
"2022-07-25 00:00:00", "2022-07-25 01:00:00", "2022-07-25 02:00:00", 
"2022-07-25 03:00:00", "2022-07-25 04:00:00", "2022-07-25 05:00:00", 
"2022-07-25 06:00:00", "2022-07-25 07:00:00", "2022-07-25 08:00:00", 
"2022-07-25 09:00:00", "2022-07-25 10:00:00", "2022-07-25 11:00:00", 
"2022-07-25 12:00:00", "2022-07-25 13:00:00", "2022-07-25 14:00:00", 
"2022-07-25 15:00:00", "2022-07-25 16:00:00", "2022-07-25 17:00:00", 
"2022-07-25 18:00:00", "2022-07-25 19:00:00", "2022-07-25 20:00:00", 
"2022-07-25 21:00:00", "2022-07-25 22:00:00", "2022-07-25 23:00:00", 
"2022-07-26 00:00:00", "2022-07-26 01:00:00"), class = "factor"), 
    Temp_mean = c(NaN, 31.9333333333333, 39.85, 42.1166666666667, 
    41.95, 38.1166666666667, 35.9333333333333, 30.7, 24.1666666666667, 
    20, 17.6166666666667, 15.8, 14.45, 13.75, 13.2, 12.5, 11.85, 
    11.0166666666667, 10.15, 10, 9.88333333333333, 9.5, 12.4, 
    21.5, 31.4833333333333, 37.6166666666667, 38.7166666666667, 
    39.2666666666667, 38.8333333333333, 36.45, 32.4166666666667, 
    26.3166666666667, 19.95, 16.3666666666667, 14.3333333333333, 
    12.4333333333333, 11.5333333333333, 12.2, 11.7666666666667, 
    11.15, 32.2333333333333, 35.2333333333333, 37.45, 38.0666666666667, 
    37.7666666666667, 35.5, 31.4666666666667, 26, 22.0666666666667, 
    19.6666666666667, 17.75, 16.45, 15.4666666666667, 14.7166666666667, 
    13.9, 13.1833333333333, 12.35, 11.5666666666667, 11, 10.85, 
    10.4833333333333, 12.1166666666667, 17.95, 25.3166666666667, 
    31.1833333333333, 33.9166666666667, 34.8833333333333, 35.05, 
    34.6333333333333, 32.3166666666667, 27.5833333333333, 22.1, 
    18.4666666666667, 16.45, 14.45, 13.05, 13.4833333333333, 
    13.0666666666667, 12.462962962963, 29.7, 32.5833333333333, 
    35.0166666666667, 36.6, 35.8166666666667, 34.15, 30.6833333333333, 
    25.2666666666667, 21.5, 19.2, 17.6333333333333, 16.4, 15.5166666666667, 
    14.8833333333333, 14.15, 13.45, 12.6833333333333, 11.8, 11.35, 
    11.15, 10.75, 11.6166666666667, 15.5833333333333, 21.5, 27.0333333333333, 
    30.8333333333333, 32.4333333333333, 32.9, 32.3166666666667, 
    30.7666666666667, 26.8833333333333, 21.4166666666667, 17.9333333333333, 
    16.1333333333333, 14.2, 12.95, 13.7, 13.6166666666667, 12.8793103448276, 
    31.9333333333333, 39.85, 42.1166666666667, 41.95, 38.1166666666667, 
    35.9333333333333, 30.7, 24.1666666666667, 20, 17.6166666666667, 
    15.8, 14.45, 13.75, 13.2, 12.5, 11.85, 11.0166666666667, 
    10.15, 10, 9.88333333333333, 9.5, 12.4, 21.5, 31.4833333333333, 
    37.6166666666667, 38.7166666666667, 39.2666666666667, 38.8333333333333, 
    36.45, 32.4166666666667, 26.3166666666667, 19.95, 16.3666666666667, 
    14.3333333333333, 12.4333333333333, 11.5333333333333, 12.2, 
    11.7666666666667, 11.15), n = c(32691L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 27L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), sd = c(NA, 1.55215830452272, 
    0.57460631200249, 0.816672531060342, 0.355983339400925, 0.897153864992658, 
    1.26445663219924, 1.92801488046912, 1.54436312804482, 0.964901281354015, 
    0.552163976977188, 0.501721175485981, 0.379427881476018, 
    0.254273813857804, 0.310727733132933, 0, 0.351106624928903, 
    0.359197701142069, 0.2330457998497, 0, 0.339455276962181, 
    0.227429413073671, 2.19482149144534, 3.01719211782446, 2.72752045200251, 
    1.17944561299917, 0.284160388577968, 0.314405112414928, 0.479463301485384, 
    1.06956323667251, 1.4388892587168, 1.90951940755157, 1.60468065358812, 
    0.706293547126578, 0.530668630505232, 0.626062315579293, 
    0.668675135459372, 0.24913643956122, 0.285673231861683, 0.2330457998497, 
    1.59597194110097, 0.504006932993731, 0.577599073454219, 0.17287295182088, 
    0.552944053622771, 0.919145030018058, 1.47352107817163, 1.420296229422, 
    0.935260735665815, 0.530668630505232, 0.521106250334738, 
    0.379427881476018, 0.34574590364176, 0.284160388577968, 0.203419051086243, 
    0.278026708383768, 0.297981716634219, 0.217086242727652, 
    0, 0.2330457998497, 0.0912870929175277, 1.39384937922073, 
    1.94470988883281, 2.20689879669426, 1.45319703041102, 0.437140657023559, 
    0.215091533576038, 0.201288949968224, 0.392457626382451, 
    0.960274146679795, 1.57613305348846, 1.55585656638792, 0.69398068806149, 
    0.577599073454219, 0.634496813937274, 0.422431385981284, 
    0.0912870929175277, 0.34072269373053, 0.133440128170906, 
    1.33649051495015, 0.542715606819131, 0.759801849546783, 0.275430697209874, 
    0.675728640359648, 0.70893314698676, 1.39261186842995, 1.41867673490507, 
    0.919145030018058, 0.518618855462641, 0.434172485455305, 
    0.357192114829753, 0.334337567729686, 0.215091533576038, 
    0.2330457998497, 0.379427881476018, 0.307473949929189, 0.24913643956122, 
    0.2330457998497, 0.2330457998497, 0.254273813857804, 0.795280619886978, 
    1.5147739864036, 1.78112711312344, 1.67606545286837, 0.647719252365604, 
    0.365148371670111, 0.203419051086243, 0.463928749979424, 
    0.653021271942343, 1.51818479029111, 1.54854399541864, 0.626062315579293, 
    0.524130368971462, 0.624223655762735, 0.273861278752583, 
    0.24913643956122, 0.215091533576038, 0.255481772266812, 1.55215830452272, 
    0.57460631200249, 0.816672531060342, 0.355983339400925, 0.897153864992658, 
    1.26445663219924, 1.92801488046912, 1.54436312804482, 0.964901281354015, 
    0.552163976977188, 0.501721175485981, 0.379427881476018, 
    0.254273813857804, 0.310727733132933, 0, 0.351106624928903, 
    0.359197701142069, 0.2330457998497, 0, 0.339455276962181, 
    0.227429413073671, 2.19482149144534, 3.01719211782446, 2.72752045200251, 
    1.17944561299917, 0.284160388577968, 0.314405112414928, 0.479463301485384, 
    1.06956323667251, 1.4388892587168, 1.90951940755157, 1.60468065358812, 
    0.706293547126578, 0.530668630505232, 0.626062315579293, 
    0.668675135459372, 0.24913643956122, 0.285673231861683, 0.2330457998497
    ), se = c(NA, 0.283384038735356, 0.104908279589538, 0.149103322452196, 
    0.0649933683619682, 0.163797136469808, 0.230857140147512, 
    0.352005747079521, 0.281960840736462, 0.176166065854411, 
    0.100810888544056, 0.0916013351305599, 0.0692737365436039, 
    0.046423834544263, 0.0567308628931175, 0, 0.0641030061876887, 
    0.0655802278398368, 0.0425481471698382, 0, 0.0619757708187835, 
    0.04152273992687, 0.400717746853915, 0.550861394419748, 0.49797482587282, 
    0.215336322530051, 0.0518803515911954, 0.0574022574215346, 
    0.0875376219064817, 0.19527463713459, 0.262704034917026, 
    0.348628951169965, 0.292973263854116, 0.128950969327188, 
    0.0968863931626966, 0.114302817548899, 0.12208281844464, 
    0.0454858826147342, 0.0521565577220158, 0.0425481471698382, 
    0.291383277762103, 0.0920186554465537, 0.105454680574986, 
    0.0315621384316, 0.100953310402513, 0.167812155519884, 0.269026911157979, 
    0.25930942773132, 0.170754467357681, 0.0968863931626966, 
    0.0951405493884234, 0.0692737365436039, 0.0631242768631999, 
    0.0518803515911954, 0.0371390676354104, 0.0507604999235668, 
    0.0544037693082247, 0.0396343440219923, 0, 0.0425481471698382, 
    0.0166666666666667, 0.254480915587923, 0.355053824639032, 
    0.402922751026818, 0.265316264685212, 0.0798105995514774, 
    0.0392701616226586, 0.0367501661580418, 0.0716526316115342, 
    0.175321270508516, 0.287761209008375, 0.2840592458844, 0.126702959108078, 
    0.105454680574986, 0.115842739219534, 0.077125066366707, 
    0.0166666666666667, 0.0622071684033784, 0.0256805646400569, 
    0.244008667643298, 0.0990858600549809, 0.138720204076973, 
    0.0502865352970744, 0.123370606359092, 0.129432892122591, 
    0.254254978062833, 0.259013749838428, 0.167812155519884, 
    0.0946864152947999, 0.0792686880439847, 0.0652140595517438, 
    0.0610414092223201, 0.0392701616226586, 0.0425481471698382, 
    0.0692737365436039, 0.0561368060738103, 0.0454858826147342, 
    0.0425481471698382, 0.0425481471698382, 0.046423834544263, 
    0.145197711686263, 0.276558627291759, 0.325187832547255, 
    0.306006285463706, 0.118256815150341, 0.0666666666666667, 
    0.0371390676354104, 0.0847014138129684, 0.119224827057846, 
    0.277181352034564, 0.282724159193322, 0.114302817548899, 
    0.0956926753863919, 0.113967125729863, 0.05, 0.0454858826147342, 
    0.0392701616226586, 0.0474417740991582, 0.283384038735356, 
    0.104908279589538, 0.149103322452196, 0.0649933683619682, 
    0.163797136469808, 0.230857140147512, 0.352005747079521, 
    0.281960840736462, 0.176166065854411, 0.100810888544056, 
    0.0916013351305599, 0.0692737365436039, 0.046423834544263, 
    0.0567308628931175, 0, 0.0641030061876887, 0.0655802278398368, 
    0.0425481471698382, 0, 0.0619757708187835, 0.04152273992687, 
    0.400717746853915, 0.550861394419748, 0.49797482587282, 0.215336322530051, 
    0.0518803515911954, 0.0574022574215346, 0.0875376219064817, 
    0.19527463713459, 0.262704034917026, 0.348628951169965, 0.292973263854116, 
    0.128950969327188, 0.0968863931626966, 0.114302817548899, 
    0.12208281844464, 0.0454858826147342, 0.0521565577220158, 
    0.0425481471698382)), row.names = c(NA, -157L), groups = structure(list(
    Type = c("", "Brown SAPE", "Brown STSA", "Green SAPE", "Green STSA"
    ), Rainfall = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0), .rows = structure(list(1L, 
        2:40, 41:79, 80:118, 119:157), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Add the output of `dput(df_Temps1.means)` to your question so we can play with it. My guess is that something is going awry with how your various `aes()` calls are interacting, and perhaps with your use of `geom_errorbar()` which works on discrete x values.

Comment: @mikeck my data is too much to paste in the box so I just put a snippet of it for playing around with it! :)

Comment: Yep, looks like `interval` is a `factor` not `POSIXct`. It also looks like you forgot to `ungroup` your data which might also be causing problems for `ggplot`. I'd try getting it working with just the lines first, then work on the errorbars after.

Comment: @mikeck okay so I used the `ungroup()` function. But as for turning interval to `POSIXct`, I already tried doing that like in my code above. I checked it using the `class()` function before using it in the plot and it came back with `"POSIXct, POSIXt"`. I'm not sure how to get it to stop being a `factor` as you say.

Comment: I suspect you are mixing up `df_Temps1`and `df_Temps1.mean` when you coerce interval to POSIXct.

Comment: @mikeck oh wow, you're so right. silly mistake. however, now I'm getting the following error trying to run my plot: `Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number`. Do you have any experience with solving this error? or know what could be causing it? Sorry to bother you again!

Comment: You should check for NA values in interval as there is at least one NA entry in the snippet you provided. But again, I suggest you first get the lines and points working, then work on adding the error bars after.